# A phrase for 'something that happens rarely'

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

Is there a phrase or idiom to describe a situation which happens rarely?

I want to use that phrase in these sentences:

> 1. You have rarely beaten me in wrestling.
> 2. Crimes used to happen rarely in Indiana.

Comment: Why do "rarely" and "rare" not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use “[count on the fingers of one hand](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/could-count-sth-on-the-fingers-of-one-hand)”.

According to Cambridge dictionary:

> If you could count something on (the fingers of) one hand, it does not happen very often or exists in very small numbers.

You could rephrase your sentences as:

> 1. I can count the number of times you have beaten me in wrestling on the fingers of one hand.
> 2. One can count the crimes that used to happen in Indiana on the fingers of one hand.

Comment: That should be: "One can count the crimes *that* used to happen in Indiana on the fingers of one hand."

Comment: @Primemover I didn’t notice that I didn’t write “that” here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of such phrases. Two fun ones are:

- once in a blue moon
- not once (or "never") in a month of Sundays (when emphasising that it's so rare you'd hardly expect it to happen at all)